# Should I implement a multithreading upload with a large number of users?

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

in my MVC 3 project there is implemented a file upload to an external system.

I've started wondering about that scenario, when at the same time e.g 100 users wants to upload a file.

Is it worthy to implement a multithreading upload ? Or maybe there are any reasons not to do this ? My server has the bandwith about 100down/60up mB/s and the files has the size lower than 100MB. It's all about the performance and time to service all the upload requests